# Can you determine if a javascript function exist on an aspx page from code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx

Seems like an easy thing, but no quite so apparently.

I have a look up page that does a complicated search of a database (first name, last_name ...) that is used as a common look up across an application.  It run through a colorbox popup and then callsback to a generic js function on the calling page to set the result on the calling page as well as close the popup.

The problem is this requires alot of setup on the calling page, including writing the callback function that sets the values.  (I can't modify the lookup page, have to work with it as is)

I've pulled the layout into a user control and now want to push the callback function to the page ONLY if another copy of the function doesn't already exist.  This is the question.  In my ascx code behind, how can I look to see if the page already contains the js function I"m looking for so that I don't duplicate that function?

Hopefully that's clear as mud.  I've been googling this for a while and haven't found anything other than how to use js to determine if a js function exist (not what I need).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That wouldn't duplicate the function. The new function would merely overwrite the old one. If it's the same function, the overwrite won't have any effect (since you're overwriting with that same function).

Comment: How exactly would you push the callback function to the page? And if it already exists on the page, in what form? (is it a global function, is it inline to the page, ...)

Comment: Would the `scripts`-collection be helpfull? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I'm not concerned necessarily with overwriting the function per instance of the control.  What I'm concerned about is overwriting and function inline with the page. (i.e. <script>function foo(){...}</script> in the markup, not injected via code-behind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method to add the script to the page:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBock(Page.GetType(), "callback", theScript, true);
```

The script will only be added to the page as long as there isn't one already added with the same type and name.

Comment: This assumes that the orginal function was added via this mechanism.  I need to know if one exist at all.  The developer has the option of writing one (hence there are already tons of pages with the function already on it).  I only want to inject the script if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @BertSmith: Then it's not possible. The script doesn't exist until it has loaded in the browser, so it's impossible to know if it exists while you are creating the page.

Comment: I give you the big green check on this one because as the question is stated and as best I can tell you're correct. This is impossible.  What I did however was dump the logic into the js script itself to check to see if the function is already defined.  Then registered the script as you suggested above.  This works perfectly now.  Thanks for the help.